# Aws-Opsworks- 2-Stack's instances are stuck at running_set-up and booting_set-up each respectively

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

new to OpsWorks I am...

And using-

1) Custom stack for Windows-os and OpsWorks-UI console

2) Custom ami to create stack's instance.

3) Instances are of "t2.micro" type and both in same subnet

I created 2 instances out of which one is stuck at "booting" other is stuck at "running-set-up" state. I refereed to -[this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/common-issues-troubleshoot.html#common-issues-troubleshoot-booting) but I can get the RDP access of the instance which is stuck at "running-set-up".

My questions-

1) Why are the instances stuck at such states? Inspite of the simple configurations done.

2) Why the other instance is stuck at "booting" state ? Although it has the same settings like the one which is stuck in  "running-set-up" state

3) What kind of settings or configurations I am missing on?

Thanks a lot for any kind of help to this !

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and it looks like you need to do a little setup on the instance you create the custom AMI from in order for OpsWorks to properly install the OpsWorks agent when it launched instances into the stack:

1. Launch new Windows 2012 R2-based instance (in our case it was the MS
   2012 R2 w/ SQL Server 2014 Web AMI)
2. Log into new instance and run EC2ConfigService Settings
3. Navigate to “Image” tab
4. Choose “Random” under “Administrator Password”
5. Click “Shutdown with Sysprep”
6. Wait for instance to shutdown and then create AMI from it
   (Right-click->Image->Create Image in the EC2 Instances Console)
7. Create a new OpsWorks stack (choosing “Microsoft Windows Server 2012
   R2 Base” or “Use custom Windows AMI” for the “Default operating
   system”)
8. Create a new layer in your stack
9. Add a new instance to your layer (choosing the AMI you created in
   Step 6 under Advanced -> Operating system)
10. Start your new instance
11. Wait to see instance status change from “booting” to
     “running_setup” (may take quite some time, 20+ minutes)

http://www.ryanmelena.com/2015/08/13/custom-windows-instance-on-aws-opsworks/

Steps 2-6 are the critical parts you need to do in order to get OpsWorks to properly initialize the instance.

Comment: - Thanks for the help... Although I deleted my all instances,layers and stack and created new respectively... and I don't know how/why its working fine now .... Sorry for the trouble and Thanks for the help... :)